# Why is DISK_FREE parameter not accurate?

Tags: operating-system, cnosdb

The metrics obtained with `show datanodes` are inaccurate

```sql
❯ show datanodes;
+---------+------------------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| NODE_ID | HOST                   | ATTRIBUTE | STATUS  | DISK_FREE | LAST_UPDATED_TIME   |
+---------+------------------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| 4       | query_tskv1.cnosdb.com | HOT       | HEALTHY | 83.32 GB  | 2023-07-06 03:12:03 |
| 5       | query_tskv2.cnosdb.com | COLD      | HEALTHY | 83.32 GB  | 2023-07-06 03:12:03 |
+---------+------------------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
Query took 0.004 seconds.
```

But the data obtained with `df -h` is:

```bash
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                  114G   31G   78G  29% /
```

The system space is shown as `78G`, but CnosDB is getting `83.32G`.

CnosDB Version:

```
cnosdb 2.3.1, revision = edf68a3430992ea27e79c7477c625c7f0ed08da7
```

Docker image

```
docker pull cnosdb/cnosdb-enterprise:2.3
```

Comment: Is the same unit used in both places? (GB vs GiB).

Comment: What is the link with Rust?

Comment: Given that `83.32 GB == 77.6 GiB`, I'd say @SirDarius is right…

Comment: [toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2023-03-10"